# android studio 2022.3.1.19 windows Could not resolve all files for configuration Error

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I use android studio 2022.3.1.19 the latest update for windows
I started the first project from "Empty Views Activity", I would say that I don't have any Error if I choose "Empty Activity" with jetpack compose
my Gradle is synced with green green tick and when I want to run Application, this error occurred

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

please help me to solve this problem

//this is my build.gradle.kts(:app)

```
plugins {
id("com.android.application")
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 31
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

}
```

//**this is my build.gradle.kts(My Application)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0-RC" apply false
}
```

I try to run the application but it doesn't work with this error

Comment: Try upgrading the ```Java``` Version to 17